# React esLint error: Missing "key" prop for element in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

This is my Code

```html
<RadioButtons
  type="test"
  field="test"
  optionInclude={['1', '2', '3']}
  optionOrder={['1', '2', '3']}
  updateValue={[
      { key: '1', value: 'test' },
      { key: '2', value: 'test2' },
      { key: '3', value: 'Other' }
  ]}
  icons={[
      <Icon variant="male" size={35} />,
      <Icon variant="female" size={35} />,
      <Icon variant="plus" size={35} />
  ]}
/>
```

When runnning EsLint i get this error:

`70:33  error  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  71:33  error  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  72:33  error  Missing "key" prop for element in array`

Line 70 - 72 is the `Icons` Array so that is what the error is referring to.

The PropTypes for the `RadioButtons` component are

```js
RadioButtons.propTypes = {
    ...
    icons: PropTypes.array,
};
```

I thought this error was for when you iterate without the key prop.

Comment: You may as well use the `variant` prop value as the `key` for each `Icon` in the array.

Comment: is it necessary for each item in an array to have a key prop? even though im not iterating . @EmileBergeron

Comment: You might not be iterating but `RadioButtons` component will be.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter about iterating. Every time you stick an array into your JSX you'll need to add keys or you'll get this warning. Remember that `.map` just returns you a new array, so iterating or not, you're still rendering an array which needs keys,

Comment: React uses it to identify similar sibling components. When you loop, really, you're just returning a new array with `map`, so it's the same.

Answer (score 10):

Since this question has no answer, I'll just reiterate what's in the comments: when you repeate *any* element in React (including your custom `Icon` element) those repeated elements must all have `key` attributes defined.

**Long Explanation About the Virtual DOM For the Curious**

The reason for this has to do with React's Virtual DOM.  A simple understanding of React works like this:

1. React renders your components to the page's DOM
2. Events happen, changing state
3. React re-renders the components that used that state to the DOM

But if it was that simple, React would be incredibly wasteful.  Imagine for instance you have a `<ul>` ...

```
<ul>
  <li>Item #1</li>
  <li>Item #2</li>
  <li>Item #3</li>
  <!--... -->
  <li>Item #25</li>
</ul>
```

(Presumably you're using a `map` to generate that in React, but how exactly you make the `<ul>` is irrelevant.)

Now, imagine that you move item #25 to be the first item in the list: if you simply re-rendered everything, you'd have to re-render 25 `<li>` elements ... even though only one of them changed.

To avoid such unnecessary (and very costly, performance-wise) DOM changes, React uses a *copy* of the DOM, known as the Virtual DOM, and the actual process looks more like:

1. React renders your components to the page's DOM
2. Events happen, changing state
3. React re-renders the components that used that state to the *Virtual* DOM
4. React does a "diff" of the old and new Virtual DOMs, and *only* updates the *actual* DOM for the parts that changed in the virtual one

This is a major performance enhancement of using React (vs. using say JQuery's `.html()` method to accomplish the same thing)!

But do you remember when we moved item #25 to #1 a moment ago?  From React's perspective, that could have been a move of #25 to #1 ... or it could have been the deletion of #25 and the insertion of a brand new `<li>` at #1 ... or it could have been a series of updates (of #1 => 25, #2 => #1, #3 => #2, ...)

In other words, React has no way of magically knowing which `<li>` is which.  Without a unique identifier on each one, a moved element can look like stuff got deleted/created, or like lots of stuff got updated.

This is where the `key` prop comes in: whenever you repeat elements (like those `<li>`s), React has difficulty telling them apart ... but it *needs to* to be able to use the Virtual DOM to make your app faster.

This is why it's not *required* that you add a key to every repeated element (React will still work if you don't) ... but you will get lots of warnings about it ... because it means you're making your app needlessly slower.